# Is it possible to hide elements that are above a matched html comment using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a weird sort of use-case where our blogging tool appends a `<!-- Read More -->` into a post and anything above that gets pushed to our listing page.

What I want to do is find the matching comment, then tell any `<p>` tag above it (in the DOM) should be set to `.hide()` or `.remove()`. Here is what I have started, I'm not quite sure if I can select a `.prevAll` on an HTML comment.

```
var content = $('.main').html();
//search for matching comment
var comment = content.match(/<!--.*?-->/);
alert(comment);
comment.prevAll('p').remove();
```

[You can see my fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/ovg04pda/)

Is there anyway to go about accomplishing this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get any comments filtering `nodeType` and checking for specific value, e.g:

```js
//find read more comment
$('*').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 8 && this.nodeValue.trim() === "Read More"; 
}).prevAll('p').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <p>
    jhkdsjhjlasfkdldfasdfd
  </p>
  <div>
    no-hide
  </div>
  <p>
    jhkdsjhjlasfkdldfasdfd
  </p>

  <!-- Read More -->

  <p>
    dfasfsfkljfaskf;sa
  </p>
  <!-- test -->
</div>
```

Comment: Dang, you beat me to it xP

Comment: This was perfect! Appreciate the help, was truly racking my brain to figure something out!